# laravel - make an script to automatically send request as test to all api s

Tags: laravel, api, testing

I have some APIs that I want to test. I know that all of them working but if I want to test all together is there a way to make a test request and send it to all urls and get the response from it some how the job that we do with post man 1 by 1 I want to do it automatically for all of the routes and APIs
here is my route list :

```
/*************************************************
 *
 * Accommodation Api Crud
 *
 **************************************************/
Route::resource('accommodation','AccommodationController');
/*************************************************
 *
 * AccommodationFacilities Api Crud
 *
 **************************************************/
Route::resource('accommodationfacilities','AccommodationFacilityController');
/*************************************************
 *
 * AccommodationRoom Api Crud
 *
 **************************************************/
Route::resource('accommodationroom','AccommodationRoomController');
/*************************************************
 *
 * accommodationbooking Api Crud
 *
 **************************************************/
Route::resource('accommodationbooking','AccommodationBookingController');
/*************************************************
 *
 * accommodationstatuslog Api Crud
 *
 **************************************************/
Route::resource('accommodationstatuslog','AccommodationStatusLogController');
/*************************************************
 *
 * accommodationbookingstatuslog Api Crud
 *
 **************************************************/
Route::resource('accommodationbookingstatuslog','AccommodationBookingStatusLogController');
/*************************************************
 *
 * RoomCapacity History Api Crud
 *
 **************************************************/
Route::resource('roomcapacityhistory','RoomCapacityHistoryController');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read the documentation, and especially the [section about testing](https://laravel.com/docs/master/http-tests). This is what that part of Laravel is made for!